# Hi everyone is there any wordpress voting plugin with payment option?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i'm building a pageant website with voting capabilities and after doing some research I cant seem to find one with payment options.

I already tried lots of voting plugin but I cant find any plugin payment option is there any that you can recommend